# Http 502 Error when trying to get InputStream in my Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, inputstream, google-search-appliance

I am using a 3rd party Java API to get results from Google Search Appliance in my Spring based web project. The URL the API constructed seem correct. I've sent a request on web browser with generated URL by API and it worked (search results returned correctly). Moreover, I've tried the URL with standalone Java project that I created to get InputStream and it worked too. The problem comes out when I try to get results in my project. It crashes on the stage of creating InputStream and gives this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: http://myIP:80/search?access=p&output=xml&client=default_frontend&lr=lang_en&num=100&requiredfields=gsaentity_language%3AEnglish&site=default_site
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
    at net.sf.gsaapi.GSAClient.search(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.gsaapi.GSAClient.getGSAResponse(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.gsaapi.GSAClient.getGSAResponse(Unknown Source)
```

The things I've tried that didn't work for me so far:

- I've used the API's interface (overriding) to handle HttpConnection and creating InputStream manually. Via this interface, some proxy options can be added to HttpConnection. (The interface named GSAClientDelegate with method getResponseStream)
- I've checked API's codes in case of finding something that causing proxy trouble etc. I couldn't find any something like that.
- As stated on an answer, I've checked collection, frontend,proxystylesheet names and they are ok. Otherwise I couldn't reach the results via web browser or standalone Java project right?

It's been almost 1 week I keep facing this annoying and mysterious error and I'm starting to go mad.

What can I do about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally figured out the base of the problem. It is because of the java.net.HttpUrlConnection API. It uses shared connection factory, which may cause the errors like this. I've replaced it with Apache HttpClient. And no problem showed up:

```
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    .........
public InputStream getConnectionStream(String fullUrl){
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(fullUrl);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

        return is;
}
```

Comment: After many many hours of trying to resolve 502 HTTP error with InputStream this finally solved my issue... Big thank You!!! I had a problem that i could run a java code from docker that downloaded a file using InputStream with no problem. But the problem started to appear when I wanted to do this via proxy. And using Apache HttpClient it went super smoothly!

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and it turned out that I just forgot to encode a space in the URL (which a browser does for you silently). Replacing the space by %20 did the trick ...
I did not try HttpClient but it may encode correctly without asking.

Comment: This does not exactly answer the question. The URL seems valid and does not contain any special character such as space. Maybe you could move this to a comment instead of writing an answer?

Comment: I do agree that my answer does not match exactly the question, but if you type "HttpURLConnection 502" in google, you will not find a lot more answers that this thread, and if my mistake can avoid other people to loose as much time as I did, then my answer is not that useless. And I do not have enough reputation to make comments ;-) It seems that this answer will not help me to have more reputation ...

Answer (score 0):

First, this is a [5xx error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error), so the issue does not (generally) lie on any system that you control.  If you're consistently getting this error, then the third-party API provider you're interfacing with is having technical difficulties, and you should reach out to them as soon as possible.

Since you may be going through [a gateway or proxy](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E502.html), consider using a direct connection to the resource that you need.

Comment: I conclude that its nothing wrong with the API (I've investigated every line of the source code of the API). We now have one last thing to consider: Spring MVC framework. Cause the case, I've constructed InputStream on my own code and sent it to the API's SAX XML parser function, showed up error again on creating InputStream object. That's really out of logic.

Comment: I'd be somewhat surprised if the API generated a 502.  I could see a 500 (any exception thrown), but a 502 is something that has to do with the actual server (gateway or proxy) backing the API.  Combing through the source code wouldn't produce anything immediately obvious.   You are getting the 502 consistently, right?

Comment: Cant's say consistenly. I've seen 407 (authentication error) rarely.

Comment: Do i have to add a content header in my request? Maybe this will inform the server backing the system about content type etc.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely made a typo in a parameter of your query.

A 502 error usually means you try to load a frontend (so check client / proxystylesheet parameter) or a collection (check parameter site. default_site ? Real default is default_collection if you didn't made a new one) that doesn't exist.

Comment: default_collection does exist in my system. As you can see, I didn't specify any proxystylesheet parameter in my url. Do i have to?

Comment: The url works when i try to reach it via my browser. But in project, no luck.